# Error, no entitlements found in bundle " "

Tags: iphone, ios7, archive, xcode5, entitlements

Please can someone assist me!

I archived my app, and I get this error:

ERROR ITMS-9000 "Missing code signing entitlements. No entitlements found in bundle "com...."
for executable.

How can I resolve this?
Thank you.

Comment: check code signing and provisioning profile settings in build settings of your project

Answer (score 4):

I was having this very problem, due to a recently-introduced automated build script. The script was codesigning the resultant app bundle manually and it turned out I needed to explicitly reference an entitlements file in the codesigning step:

> /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign "$CERTIFICATE" --identifier "$BUNDLE_ID" **--entitlements Entitlements.plist** Payload/${BUNDLE_NAME}.app

The Entitlements.plist file is pretty standard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <false/>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>fully-qualified bundleid</string>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>fully-qualified bundleid</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Instead of authoring a new Entitlements file that may or may not work, you can generate one from your existing app bundle. It's like magic! `usr/bin/codesign -d --entitlements :entitlements.plist Payload/*.app` NOTE: If you put the colon before the name, you get an XML doc. Otherwise you get an SGML doc.